# 2 different results with dompdf - same template, same script different content

Tags: php, symfony, dompdf

I create PDF files in my Symfony project using the dompfd library . In this example I use the same script, the same template, the same code, but in one case I get a PDF file, in the other case I get source code. The only difference are the items in the list.
(After the code blocks the output of the erroneous PDF read source code)

Code:

```
$pdfOptions = new Options();
$pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');
$pdfOptions->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$pdfOptions->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);

$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => FALSE,
        'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
        'allow_self_signed' => TRUE
    ]
]);
$dompdf->setHttpContext($context);

$itemStocks = array();

foreach ($warehouse->getItemStocks() as $itemStock){
    if($itemStock->getMin() > $itemStock->getCount()){
        $itemStocks[] = $itemStock;
    }
}

$itemOrders = array();

foreach ($warehouse->getWarehouseItemsOrders() as $itemOrder){
    $itemOrders[] = $itemOrder;
}

$html = $this->renderView('pdf/itemstockunder.html.twig', [
    'warehouse' => $warehouse,
    'itemStocks' => $itemStocks,
    'itemOrders' => $itemOrders
]);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4');

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($warehouse->getId() . " Minderbestand.pdf", [
    "Attachment" => false
]);
```

HTML Code working example (dumped before loadHtml function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:text-align="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Artikelliste - Elbmarsch</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}
        th {border-bottom: #0b2e13 1px solid}
        td, th{padding: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Minderbestände - Elbmarsch</h2>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Min</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Ist</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Liefern</th>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Absaug-Verbindungsschlauch - CH. 25 (Accuvac)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Absaugbeutel - 1000 ml (Accuvac)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Absaugkatheter 16 - orange
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">4</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Adrenalin 1:1000 - 1 mg/1 ml (Supra)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">5</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">10</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Amiodaron - 150 mg/3 ml
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">5</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        ASS - 500mg Pulver (Aspirin)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Beatmungsbeutel Einweg - Erwachsener (Adult, Ambubeutel)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Beatmungsschlauch - Medumat Standard 2
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Defi / Pacer Eletroden - Erwachsener
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Endotrachealtubus - 5,0
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Endotrachealtubus - 7,0
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Guedel Tubus - Gr. 4
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Hautdesinfektion - 50 ml (Cutasept)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Hautdesinfektionsmittel - 250 ml (kodan)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Heparin - 5000 I.E./0,2 ml
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">4</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Händedesinfektion - 100 ml (desderman)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Infusion Vollelektrolytlösungen - 500 ml (Jonosteril)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">10</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">8</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">7</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Infusionssystem
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">8</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">5</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">15</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Isotonische Kochsalzlösung - 10 ml (NaCl 0,9)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">5</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">7</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Isotonische Kochsalzlösung - 100 ml (NaCl 0,9)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Kapnometrie - Tubus (CO2 Leitung)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Larynxtubus - Gr. 4
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Ohrthermometerkappe
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Pflasterrolle weiß - 2,5 cm (Leukoplast)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Rettungsdecke
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Sauerstoffbrille (O2 Brille)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">5</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">7</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Spitzabwurf groß
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Spritze 1 ml Heparin
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
        <p style="page-break-after: always;">Seite 1 von 2 | Minderbestand - Elbmarsch</p>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Min</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Ist</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Liefern</th>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Spritze 10ml
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">4</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">8</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Thomas Holder
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Venenstauband
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Wendel Tubus - Ch 26
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">0</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
        <p style="">Seite 2 von 2 | Minderbestand - Elbmarsch</p>
                <p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
        <h2>Bestellungen - Elbmarsch</h2>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Liefern</th>

                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            Papierhandtücher
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            5
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            Spitzabwurf Corona
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                            </table>
            <p style="">Seite 1 von 1 | Bestellungen - Elbmarsch</p>
        </body>
</html>
```

HTML Code from the non working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:text-align="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Artikelliste - Nindorf</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}
        th {border-bottom: #0b2e13 1px solid}
        td, th{padding: 5px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Minderbestände - Nindorf</h2>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Min</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Ist</th>
                <th style="text-align:right;">Liefern</th>
            </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        BZ Sensoren (Blutzuckersensoren)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Hautdesinfektion - 50 ml (Cutasept)
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Stifneck Select - Erwachsener
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">3</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                        Venenstauband
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">1</td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
        <p style="">Seite 1 von 1 | Minderbestand - Nindorf</p>
                <p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
        <h2>Bestellungen - Nindorf</h2>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right;">Liefern</th>

                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            Alufolie
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;border-bottom: #0b2e13 solid 1px">
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                            </table>
            <p style="">Seite 1 von 1 | Bestellungen - Nindorf</p>
        </body>
</html>
```

one-liner HTML also doesn't work:

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:text-align="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de"><head><title>Artikelliste - Elbmarsch</title><style type="text/css">body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}</style></head><body><h2>Minderbestände - Elbmarsch</h2><div>Test</div></body></html>';
```

Output of the erroneous PDF:

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
10 0 R
]
/Count 2
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Producer (��dompdf <6782abfc> + CPDF)
/CreationDate (D:20220930161417+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20220930161417+00'00')
/Title (��Artikelliste - Nindorf)
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 599 >>
stream
x����n�@��<�Y&�N=wϖ(i�]�E�,��ʗF���}�� �x<�q�`t�3����X%$I���x
\��*�Z��i�.��
���K���oY��œ-���>�w,l���#Lo�z��U�P.@J��~�W�7��_�:�I�HTO#Ƈ
B�R����I
���4|���m
NGp�Mw��~|�"^_!�[�x�?��^�6��8����&���D+��j�94��0�y�-l�u]���-ʦ�p���b7 'bDPN�`]��ޠxYB�Zɽ �q4�'��E�n@*J�q���H*�r
)%F�PaS�*TF��c_��Y]-l��K���m��D&�Y�ϫ����W5Ԣg���8���n�l`1
j,��,� o��,��D�E�"�,�JdQsb�>`qRe���Wx�v^����u6��h�A�Z7���!�8�AP3�8��;4��A�^����a�Q4��T�s��ؽكƦiGN���w�7/�Y�4��4{X��l�tvi�    q�8��3y1
:#D���"{1��~k�B����.�ߔۯ �(I���f�
���N��_E�e�?��v��
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Times-Roman
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F2
/BaseFont /Times-Bold
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 11 0 R
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<< /Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 264 >>
stream
x���AO�0����L��Izd M��mډ��R�Je  ��IѨ��*۱��>[Y(RJ!��n��'�ߦ�<�f̟PXalcQ.�2C�-��ڡ(q�����
�\-��!4ͱ݅7x�۲��-����mFV3�a2"��N<�B���F�T(��h=#|�C�vM-�A����#Ob��i��2S�Tx���D���<�&���k�U��a�j�Lښ�9/��9���9'唔����~����P]�7��td�\
endstream
endobj
xref
0 12
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000074 00000 n 
0000000120 00000 n 
0000000291 00000 n 
0000000320 00000 n 
0000000535 00000 n 
0000000638 00000 n 
0000001309 00000 n 
0000001418 00000 n 
0000001526 00000 n 
0000001631 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 12
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 5 0 R
/ID[<c3997b02011092bcc947178b29f2b1a0><c3997b02011092bcc947178b29f2b1a0>]
>>
startxref
1968
%%EOF
```

Comment: @KJ I tried a one-liner (I added it above), it doesn't work with that either. Strangely only with the long HTML code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. How should i look in the pdf? The erroneous code does not output a pdf file. What I have posted is the text in the browser window.